# Java - How to encrypt passwords for wordpress?

Tags: java, wordpress, encryption

How can i encrypt password to get the same output like wordpress to compare it later with my db ?

Comment: WordPress uses MD5 encryption for its passwords - is that what you want to know?

Comment: Not quite sure why this is being down- and close-voted...? (Well, the downvotes could be about research...)

Comment: @entreprenerds: :-) Separately, a quick search suggests that Wordpress doesn't use straight MD5...

Comment: What use wordpress then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) **WordPress** uses the `PasswordHash` class from the [**phpass**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for generating the password hashes. According to the links, the default implementation used involves the use of a salt, and 8 rounds of MD5 hashing. Exactly how and when the salt is applied, and what goes into the MD5 don't seem to be readily available. However, there seem to be a [**java port of phpass here.**](https://github.com/Mollom/phpass-java)

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, WordPress uses MD5 to encrypt *its* passwords. Here's a link to some code about password hashing in PHP, which I think might be what you're looking for:

[Password Hashing In PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/password-hashing-in-php/)

Comment: i need to get encryt a string so dath when i compare it with my db from wordpress i need to do this in java